# Adding Image to Xaml not rendering with given margin

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, stackpanel

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{ 
    Image img1 ;
    img1 = null;
    img1= new Image();

    img1.Height = snhei;    
    img1.Width = snwid;
    BitmapImage BitImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/midtail.png", UriKind.Relative));`

    img1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    img1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    img1.Source = BitImg;
    img1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    img1.Name = "mid" + i.ToString() ;
    img1.Margin = new Thickness(image_width*i, 0, 0, 0);

    stackp.Children.Add(img1);
}
```

after running i get first image at 0,0
then it is render the one image_width below

Comment: The container name `stackp` suggests you're using a StackPanel. Just set its `Orientation` property to `Horizontal` and don't set any margins on the images.

Comment: @Clemens i ran  app like you said . why the images are not overlapping? **i want images to overlap**

Comment: No idea what you mean. Please add some details to your question about what exactly you are going to achieve. A screenshot or a sketch might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your container. The StackPanel will, as it name indicates, try to stack the images. Then you apply the margin, moving the picture farther away.

You have two solutions, depending on what you want:

- If you just want the images to be displayed side by side, set the `Orientation` property of your StackPanel to `Horizontal`. Then, remove your line of code that sets the margin, since the positioning is automatically handled by the StackPanel
- If you still want to position the pictures manually, then you have to use another type of container. Replace your StackPanel by a Canvas or a Grid.